# How to get log at run time when force close in Android application

Tags: android

How to get log at run time when force close in Android application.
I want to get logs and mail it.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the display the logs on your phone screen?

Comment: yes, after getting logs I will send it to developer for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here some code to collect logs inside application:

```
    private int MAX_LOG_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 100000;
    private String[] mFilterSpecs;
    private String mFormat;
    private String mBuffer;

private class CollectLogTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, StringBuilder> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected StringBuilder doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {
        final StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            ArrayList<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<String>();
            commandLine.add("logcat");//$NON-NLS-1$
            commandLine.add("-d");//$NON-NLS-1$
            ArrayList<String> arguments = ((params != null) && (params.length > 0)) ? params[0] : null;
            if (null != arguments) {
                commandLine.addAll(arguments);
            }

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine.toArray(new String[0]));
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                log.append(line);
                log.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CollectLogTask.doInBackground failed", e);//$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        return log;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final StringBuilder log) {
        if (null != log) {
            // truncate if necessary
            int keepOffset = Math.max(log.length() - MAX_LOG_MESSAGE_LENGTH, 0);
            if (keepOffset > 0) {
                log.delete(0, keepOffset);
            }

            if (mAdditonalInfo != null) {
                log.insert(0, LINE_SEPARATOR);
                log.insert(0, mAdditonalInfo);
            }
                          Log.d("printLog",log.toString());

        }
    }
}
```

Now call this async class like this.

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (mFormat != null) {
        list.add("-v");
        list.add(mFormat);
    }

    if (mBuffer != null) {
        list.add("-b");
        list.add(mBuffer);
    }

    if (mFilterSpecs != null) {
        for (String filterSpec : mFilterSpecs) {
            list.add(filterSpec);
        }
    }

    new CollectLogTask().execute(list);
```

Comment: Note that this code will not work on Android 4.1 and higher, except to collect your own process' logs, as ordinary SDK apps can no longer hold the `READ_LOGS` permission.

Comment: Ya i know that but the question was to only get the application logs of own process, As evident from question he want to collect logs on force close.

Comment: Oh, I am not complaining about your answer. I am merely mentioning it for people who come across this question and answer in the future. I didn't mention the limitation in my answer because it's covered in the ACRA docs.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ACRA](http://acra.ch/), or related libraries, to catch crashes from production apps and process those reports. By default, ACRA will log the material to a Google Docs spreadsheet, but you can replace that with something else.

Answer (score 1):

`adb logcat` when device is connected in USB-debug

or

install [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=fr) from gplay.