# Save stacktrace on phone

Tags: android, stack-trace

I encounter an error on a friend's phone and I can't figure out why the app is force closing in an activity. Is it possible to somehow save the stacktrace in a log file that he can send me?

Comment: Is this distributed via the Play store?

Comment: Just download LOGCAT EXTREME, if his phone is rooted then it's free and everything and can send it as an email

Answer (score 0):

Add the following permission to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
```

+

[How to get log at run time when force close in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860967/how-to-get-log-at-run-time-when-force-close-in-android-application)